# Debian - How do I install a specific, old version of a package? "The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG"

Tags: debian, apt

After searching around for a long time, I finally found a specific package I needed to install for a VM setup of an intentionally vulnerable machine. The package in question is `openssl` 1.0.2-1 and I am having a lot of trouble trying to install it. The package is located in https://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20150123T220434Z. I have already added a deb entry for the snapshot repo in my `sources.list.d/` and added the necessary key with `apt-key` but now I am getting the following error when running `sudo apt update`:

```bsh
Err:9 https://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20150123T220434Z unstable InRelease
  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 8B48AD6246925553 Debian Archive Automatic Signing Key (7.0/wheezy) <ftpmaster@debian.org>
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: https://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20150123T220434Z unstable InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 8B48AD6246925553 Debian Archive Automatic Signing Key (7.0/wheezy) <ftpmaster@debian.org>
E: The repository 'https://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20150123T220434Z unstable InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I'm not sure how to deal with this, as I think that I've already added the key. If someone could point me in the right direction on how to fix this, that would be great. Alternatively, maybe there is a better way of installing these obsolete(?) packages, since I'm going to be doing this sort of thing repeatedly for my setup.

Comment: Does https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/75807/117549 help?

Comment: If the key itself is expired, I think you might need to use `Acquire::Check-Valid-Until no` in apt configuration. See, e.g., what the user does in https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/600510/70524

Answer (score 5):

You’ve correctly added the repository key, but it’s expired, so `apt` won’t consider its signatures as valid. You’ll have to tell `apt` to trust the repository anyway; edit the repository line [so it starts with](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/apt/sources.list.5)

```
deb [trusted=yes] https://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/... wheezy main
```

The [snapshot instructions](https://snapshot.debian.org/) mention `check-valid-until=no`, but that’s not sufficient once the signing key has expired.